# Error copyfile2 could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll after installing Adobe Photoshop

Tags: dynamic, adobe, photoshop, file-copying

I have windows 7 installed on my laptop. I installed Adobe Photoshop ..After Successful installation when i am trying to open it , it gives me the error "copyfile2 could not be located in the dynamic link library kernel32.dll". I also checked my kernal32.dll file it is also present
Even I again done windows on my system but still facing the same issue.. Kindly guide me

Answer (score 1):

The command CopyFile2 has been introduced in Windows 8.
So it is correct that this command cannot be found in Kernel32.dll on Windows 7.

See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-copyfile2
(On the bottom is written "Minimum supported client: Windows 8 [desktop apps | UWP apps]")

So I guess this Photoshop version cannot be used on Windows 7.